# How to set up identical/similar keybindings in a virtualized Windows 10 (VMware Fusion) and OS X?

Tags: mac, windows, vmware, keybindings

I am new to Mac and now also new to the Windows 10 environment so on a huge learning curve. I have managed to set up Office via VMware Fusion virtual machine on my Mac.

I need to find out how I can mainly find the @ key to work on the Windows side. Or is there a way to make the keyboard work the same on both sides for applications? I will be working in both environments seamlessly so if I can have the same keys work in both that would be great.

Comment: Please add your preferred Windows & OS X keyboard layouts

Comment: Are you in the UK?  Most people who have trouble with the @ key are just using the wrong keyboard layout in their Windows OS.  Windows UK layouts have @ over at shift ' instead of shift 2 (if that is where you are expecting it).  Switching to the US layout will fix this, or to British (Apple) if there is one of those.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the keyboards should behave similarly with the exception of the Command key.

Go to your Virtual Machine settings and click on Keyboard & Mouse, in there you can pick a profile, the default works pretty well. You can do Shift + 2 and it will give you the @ symbol.

Your Command key on Mac is equivalent to the Control key on Windows, you can change this if required in the key mapping area.